# Add powershell script to c# code

Tags: .net, powershell, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, powershell-2.0

I want to execute a powershell script from C# code. I don't want to store my powershell script on any folder. script is kind of BIG and it has a parameters a "List" and "string", how to do this.

```
    $ComputerName = "win12"
    $username="administrator"
    $password="passw0rd@12"

   $secstr = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.SecureString
   $password.ToCharArray() | ForEach-Object {$secstr.AppendChar($_)}
   $fname="v.exe"
   $fname="C:\"+$fname

     $cr = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $secstr
      $Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $ComputerName -Credential $cr
       Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock {
  Start-Process -FilePath $($args[0]) -ArgumentList '/a' -Verb runas -WindowStyle Normal
  $process=[io.path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension( $($args[0]));
 $a = (Get-Process -Name $process)
 $a.PriorityClass = [System.Diagnostics.ProcessPriorityClass]::RealTime
  } -ArgumentList $fname
```

this is my powershell script.

Comment: Have you looked at [PowerShell.Invoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd182449%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)? Did Google and StackOverflow searches turn up nothing of value?

Answer (score 2):

Store the PowerShell script as an embedded resource in the assembly then at runtime extract the script and supply it to the [PowerShell.AddScript(string script)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd182436(v=vs.85).aspx) method.  The call the [PowerShell.Invoke()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd182449(v=vs.85).aspx) method to execute the script.